# What does it mean to set $\delta$ to a minimum?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

If we were to prove $\lim_{x \to 4} \sqrt{x} = 2$, then by using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, we have:

$0 \leq |\sqrt{x} - 2| < \epsilon$

$-\epsilon< \sqrt{x} - 2 < \epsilon$

$2 -\epsilon< \sqrt{x} < 2 + \epsilon$

$(2 -\epsilon)^{2}< x < (2 + \epsilon)^{2}$

$4 -4\epsilon +\epsilon^{2}< x < 4 +4\epsilon -\epsilon^{2}$

Now, we set $\delta \leq \min(4\epsilon +\epsilon^{2}, 4\epsilon -\epsilon^{2})$ and choose whichever is smaller.

Since $\epsilon > 0$, the minimum is $\delta \leq 4\epsilon -\epsilon^{2}$

**Source:** Hartman, G. (n.d.). 1.2: Epsilon-Delta Definition of a Limit. LibreTexts. Retrieved April 29, 2021, from https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(Apex)/01%3A_Limits/1.02%3A_Epsilon-Delta_Definition_of_a_Limit

**Remark:** I paraphrased what the author said, including only the key points, but the computations remain the same.

From the above, I have some questions, which I'll list as follows:

1. The minimum, according to the source, is $\delta \leq 4\epsilon -\epsilon^{2}$. **Is this because that's the only value $\delta$ that guarantees, for every $x$ within $\delta$ units from $4$, $f(x)$ is to be within $\epsilon$ units from 2?**
2. Does the need for minimum come from the fact that the distance between $4$ and $4 - \delta$ and the distance between $4$ and $4 + \delta$ is not the same?
3. Is the distance between $4$ and $4 - \delta$ and the distance between $4$ and $4 + \delta$ not the same because the function we're evaluating is non-linear? Does this mean that the distances from $4$ are to be the same when the function is linear?
4. Why can $\delta$ be made smaller than the minimum?

Please let me know if I've made myself understood as I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: Take care if $2-\epsilon<0?$

Comment: To prove a limit with $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, you'll need to find some $\delta$ satifying the inequation. If it turns out there's 2 condition, you need to satisfy them both. And of course the $\delta$ isn't unique, considering it can be smaller then any choose of $\delta$ satifying the equation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: If $x>2-\epsilon$, it is not generally true that $x^2>(2-\epsilon)^2.$ For example, with $\epsilon=3$ and $x=0.$

Comment: Also, $(2-\epsilon)^2=4-4\epsilon+\epsilon^2.$ You have $-\epsilon^2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndres Yes, I accidentally switched signs.

Comment: It’s nice to handle the large $\epsilon$ case, but not really necessary since satisfying a small $\epsilon$ also satisfies the larger one.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews "If $x > 2 -\epsilon$, it is not generally true that...". Well, if that's the case, then we have $|a| < \delta$, which I think is false as |a| is greater.

Comment: Yes, but doing dangerous things with inequalities should always be corrected in early proofs, IMHO, @eric The other “large epsilon” problem is that it can give $\delta<0$ when $\epsilon>4.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews By definition, $\delta$ can't be less than zero, that is, negative.

Comment: @Nameless For the proof to work, sure, $\delta<0$ is not allowed. But as defined, when $\epsilon>4$ then $\delta<\min(4\epsilon-\epsilon^2,4\epsilon+\epsilon^2)<0.$ That’s why you have to take care in cases like this.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think I understood what you said, but could you post an answer just to make sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The minimum, according to the source, is δ≤4ϵ−ϵ2. Is this because that's the only value δ that guarantees, for every x within δ units from 4, f(x) is to be within ϵ units from 2?

Because for any $\epsilon$, with that choose of $\delta$,
$$ 4-\delta < x < 4+\delta \implies 2 - \epsilon < f(x) < 2 + \epsilon $$
And this satifies(actually, this **is**) the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. So your statement is basically correct, the only problem is "the only value $\delta$ that satifies". Fix $\epsilon$, then with smaller choose of $\delta$, let's say some $\delta'$ < $\delta$,
$$ 4-\delta' < x < 4+\delta' \implies 4-\delta < x < 4+\delta \implies 2 - \epsilon < f(x) < 2 + \epsilon $$
So in fact, any smaller choose of $\delta$ satifies the inequality.

2. Does the need for minimum come from the fact that the distance between 4 and 4−δ and the distance between 4 and 4+δ is not the same?

I think you mean the distance between f(4) and f(4−δ) copmared to f(4) with f(4+δ). Yes. Because you need different choose of $\delta$ to satify both sides of the inequality, and you have to make the both sides correct to prove it satifies the definition.

3. Is the distance between 4 and 4−δ and the distance between 4 and 4+δ not the same because the function we're evaluating is non-linear? Does this mean that the distances from 4 are to be the same when the function is linear?

I think you mean the distance between $f(4)$ and $f(4-δ)$ copmared to $f(4)$ with $f(4+δ)$. Yes, because we're evaluating a non-linear function. When the function is linear, it's clear that
$$ f(4) - f(4-\delta) = f(4+\delta) - f(4)$$

4. Why can δ be made smaller than the minimum?

Look 1.

Comment: OP: Can you please explain what do you mean by "the only value δ that guarantees" in the first question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. By "the only value $\delta$ that guarantees...", I mean, from the values in $\min$, i.e., $4\epsilon +\epsilon^{2}$ and $4\epsilon -\epsilon^{2} $, only one satisfies the implicaiton given in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, which is not true. As you pointed out, $\delta$ can be made smaller than the minimum. Thus, $\delta \leq 4\epsilon -\epsilon^{2} $.

Comment: Does this answer your question, then?

Comment: I'm reading your post. So far, it has cleared up some of my doubts.